# Validating + submitting an iOS app bundle identifier issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I seem to be hitting a wall here, been trying everything I could so here I am. I am trying to build my first app and submit it to the store following this [article](https://medium.com/@_qzapaia/deploy-an-ionic-app-to-the-ios-app-store-702c79a2dd97). I get to the point where I archive the project and then either attempt to Upload to the App Store or Validate.

After choosing either option I get to pick a Development Team to use for provisioning. Pretty straightforward, I get no choice but to select the only team available and hit Choose. Then the archive gets prepared and I see a summary window.

[image]

After clicking on Validate, I get the following error.

[image]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong at the moment, any help would be welcome, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure "iTunes Connect the app has to be in the state of 'waiting for upload'"?

Comment: @anhtu Hmm, did not know about that, how do I set it up? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didn't set up the iTunes connect for your app yet.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html

Comment: Yes seems to be the issue, I am trying to do that now, thanks!